# How to stop c# of changing my date to numbers?

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, format

I am currently working on a project and I want to insert my excel to a datagridview.

But my date (format special: d/mm/jjjj u:mm (Belgium)) [excel format d/mm/jjjj u:mm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds5Om.png) keeps turning into numbers. How do I stop this 
[datagridview numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnt2l.png)?

I am currently using an openfiledialog and putting it in a combobox in case there are more sheets.

```
using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
                    reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                    result = reader.AsDataSet();
                    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                    }
                    reader.Close();

                }
            }
```

then I am just using this to show it in my datagridview

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = result.Tables[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];

    }
```

I'm still a learning student. Now working as an intern for two weeks.

Comment: Are you using the `DateTime` type for your column in the Data Grid View? Are you using `DateTime.ParseExact`?

Comment: That's exactly how Excel stores dates - as OADate numbers. C# didn't change anything, either you read the dates as numbers, or you don't really have an Excel file and read the data from a CSV. Post your code

Comment: How did you read the data? OLEDB should recognize this as a Date. If you used a DataTable with DateTime columns, the conversion would also be automatic.

Comment: `CreateBinaryReader` is only used with the obsolete `xls` format. Excel uses the `xlsx` format since 2007, which is a compressed collection of XML files.

Comment: The files that i got are XLS formats

Comment: Use `AsDataset(true)` to convert OADates to dates. This is the default behaviour in `ExcelOpenXmlReader`. The `ExcelBinaryReader` though uses a default of `false`.

Comment: @RobbeDeClercq *don't* use that format. It's obsolete for a reason. The only supported way to create it was to use Excel directly or a very limited OLEDB provider. The 10-year old `xlsx` format can be generated by anyone - it's just a set of well-documented XML files. It can be generated on a web server using only XML manipulation.

Comment: @RobbeDeClercq the reason `ExcelBinaryReader` uses an inconsistent default is probably because it *wasn't* tested as well as the newer format.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The AsDataset(true) worked thanks for that! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reader.AsDataSet(true);` instead of `reader.AsDataSet();`

From the snippet, it appears that [Excel Data Reader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) is used to read an old `xls`-format file. Excel uses the "newer" `xlsx` format since 2007. 
The package offers one reader for the old format (ExcelBinaryReader) and one for the current format `ExcelOpenXmlReader`.

Unfortunately, the `AsDataSet()` method uses different defaults with the old and new format. Dates are converted automatically only in the current format. In the old format, you have to use the `AsDataSet(bool)` overload to convert the values explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The format strings you are using are specifying that.

Try something like "ddd/MMMM/jjjj".

Theres a lot of options on this front ...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores DateTime values as floating point values internally.  It's not C# that is making the dates into numbers.  If you get a DateTime value from Excel, you can convert it to a C# DateTime using DateTime.FromOADate(double).

Example:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.FromOADate((double)excelDateTime);
```

Comment: *doubles*, not integers

Comment: Besides, OLEDB would recognize the DateTime value without requiring conversions. There must be a different problem with the OP's code that loads dates as doubles

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos True, it should.  But in this case is isn't for some reason, so this way he can convert the values to a date.  If he wants a solution to why he is not loading the data correctly, he will have to post code.

Comment: I am importing this excel via openfiledialog then putting it in a combobox (if there are more sheets in the excel document) So how do i use you're example then (I'm not the best coder so i don't understand what u mean) the collumn of this problem in the datagrid is collumn 6

Comment: @RobbeDeClercq How are you loading the excel file?  OpenFileDialog allows the user to select a file, but what code are you using to actually open the file?